# Understand accelerometer value

Tags: kinematics, reference-frames, acceleration, si-units

I'am using an accelerometer, so if I put my accelerometer on a table for example I got gravity 9.8, I have this result by this formula : $\sqrt{x^2+ y^2 + z^2}$, ok so now if I lift quickly my captor I got a value 15 for example, what's the meaning of this number? My captor has encoutered an 5,2g acceleration (15 - 9.8) is it right ? And If I let it down my captor I got for exemple 5, my captor encoutered -4,8g?

Comment: You can add mathematical equations to questions using MathJax for future reference.

Comment: What do you mean by "captor"?

Comment: @ChrisLong Yes thanks I'll know for future question, my captor is an accelerometer build on an Arduino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you mean with "this formula": $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$? I don't see. But on the table, $9.8$ means $9.8\mathrm m/\mathrm s^2$
so acceleration upward gives you $5.2\mathrm m/\mathrm s^2$ (not $5.2g$).

Comment: Ah yes you've right, so 5,2m/s^2 is equal to 0.5g ? So if my captor returns to me 16m/s^2, I have 1,6g or 0.6g (result of 16 - 9.8)?

Comment: yes exactly you got it.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, an accelerometer measures the magnitude and direction of the force acting on a reference mass. The output would be scaled so that it appears be  the force on a 1 kg mass.  If the mass is at rest on the surface of the earth, you get the acceleration of gravity.  If you accelerate it upward, a greater force is required. Subtract out the (g), and you get the upward acceleration.